# List Entity Relationships in Dynamics CRM 2013/2015

Tags: c#, powershell, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics

Is it possible to return a list of relationships on a particular type of entity (not an individual record) using the CRM/XRM SDK?

For example, if I have an entity called "Case" and I need to see if it has a relationship with "MyCustomEntity" is it possible to query the schema of the "Case" entity in CRM and find a list of relationships, checking for one relating to "MyCustomEntity". Similar to expanding the "1:N Relationships" tab in Customisations.

I Have found this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509021.aspx which explains creating a new relationship, but nowhere to say "These are the relationships that X has"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you retrieve the entity via the metadata service, you can get to the relationships through the EntityMetadata property on the RetrieveEntityResponse. Here is an example:

```
     RetrieveEntityRequest retrieveBankAccountEntityRequest = new RetrieveEntityRequest
     {
         EntityFilters = EntityFilters.Relationships,
         LogicalName = "account"
     };
     RetrieveEntityResponse retrieveBankAccountEntityResponse = (RetrieveEntityResponse)service.Execute(retrieveBankAccountEntityRequest);

     var oneToNRelationships = retrieveBankAccountEntityResponse.EntityMetadata.OneToManyRelationships;
```

Here's a list of the properties of the response: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.metadata.entitymetadata_members.aspx

Comment: If all you need are the relationships you can use `EntityFilters.Relationships`  instead of `EntityFilters.All` for a slight performance bump - less to retrieve and transfer. It may not have a major impact, but best practice is to not retrieve more entity metadata than your code will need.